# How can I put the button to bottom?

Tags: android

I have the following layout with a Google map fragment. Now I want to put a Scrollview at the bottom but I don't know how. Please help me! Thank you so much!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.testgoogle.MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_find"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/str_btn_find" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/et_location"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_find"
        android:hint="@string/hnt_et_location"
        android:textColorHint="#d9d7d7"
        android:ems="10" >
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

</RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you want to place ScrollView below map fragment??

Comment: If you want the ScrollView below the map fragment, you can just enter the ScrollView as the next element below fragment in your LinearLayout. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Paid your attention - your MapFragment has match_parent height so your ScrollView will be not visible as soon as there is no place left for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.testgoogle.MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_find"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/str_btn_find" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/et_location"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_find"
        android:hint="@string/hnt_et_location"
        android:textColorHint="#d9d7d7"
        android:ems="10" >
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

</RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_container"
    android:layout_above="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <!--Your scroll view content-->
    ...
    ...  
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But **NOTE**, that your map height will depends on `ScrollView`'s height. It should be fixed size(i.e. **50dp**). But content of the `ScrollView` should be with `wrap_content` height.

Comment: `wrap_content` on a `ScrollView`? That should either be a fixed height, or a calculated height, but `wrap_content` and `ScrollView` are not supposed to be used together. Just imagine what the result would look like, a `ScrollView` which wraps its content can't do much scrolling...

Comment: Yes, sure, you are right, I was confused, fixed size should be for `ScrollView` and `wrap_content` for the content, edited.